# bottom-bar inflating exception in 21 API

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-library

I am using bottom-bar in my android project. I always used to the API 24. But When I tried to use API 21. My project gives an exception. I searched on the internet. But I did not find anything. When I pass to activity that in bottom-bar .İt gives me the exception. By the way; I searched for my project and there is no codding mistake. While I erased my bottom-bar from my layout. The exception has gone. How can I fix it?

My tabs :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab
        id="@+id/ana"
        icon="@drawable/news"
        title="Vitrin" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/find"
        icon="@drawable/foot"
        title="Ziyaretçi" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/add"
        icon="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_black_24dp"
        title="" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/chat"
        icon="@drawable/chat"
        title="Mesajlar" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/user"
        icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        title="Profil" />
</tabs>
```

My library in my gradle:

> compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'

Bottom-bar layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".bottom_bar">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>


    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/tab" >

    </com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar>



</LinearLayout>
```

My logcat :

```
05-06 18:36:29.348 2616-2616/something.about.berkay.isim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: something.about.berkay.isim, PID: 2616
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{something.about.berkay.isim/something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar.onCreate(bottom_bar.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar.onCreate(bottom_bar.java:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080078
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBarTab.prepareLayout(BottomBarTab.java:102)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.updateItems(BottomBar.java:351)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.setItems(BottomBar.java:310)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.setItems(BottomBar.java:293)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.init(BottomBar.java:148)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.<init>(BottomBar.java:127)
        at com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.<init>(BottomBar.java:122)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar.onCreate(bottom_bar.java:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Did you add a tab.xml to your resources...? If you have, it's complaining about a missing drawable/icon.

Comment: Yes. I did. I am editing now.

Comment: Duke. Thank you. There is problem in icons. Please answer my question. Your answer is true. By the way  ; How to understand that there is problem in icons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the stacktrace you can see:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080078       
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
```

So it's a problem with the icons ;)